# How to send images from PC to Android by using Socket?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I send a image using this code in pc:

```
public static void sendImage(File image,Socket socket) throws IOException {

    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

    BufferedImage Bimage = ImageIO.read(image);

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(Bimage, "png", byteArrayOutputStream);

    byte[] size = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(byteArrayOutputStream.size()).array();
    outputStream.write(size);
    System.out.println("size");
    outputStream.write(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
    System.out.println("BT");
    outputStream.flush();
}
```

And I receive the image using this code in android:

```
private void show_imageFromService() throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = CreateActivity.client.socket.getInputStream();

    byte[] sizeAr = new byte[4];
    inputStream.read(sizeAr);
    int size = ByteBuffer.wrap(sizeAr).asIntBuffer().get();

    byte[] imageAr = new byte[size];
    inputStream.read(imageAr);

    Rect rect=new Rect();
    rect.set(imageView.getLeft(),imageView.getTop(),imageView.getRight(),imageView.getBottom());

    BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize=1;

    Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAr,0,imageAr.length,options);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

}
```

But the image can't show in android, can anyone have other way to deal with this?

Comment: You should try to debug the code by logging the values of size of `bytearray` and other suspicious code in both android and pc's code. Did you make sure that server-client connection was properly established?

Comment: You don't need any ImageIO here. Just read the file and copy the bytes. And don't assume that `read()` fills the buffer.

Comment: On both sides print the value of the four size bytes in hexadecimal notation. You probably have to swap some bytes before the integer size has equal values on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the send code:

```
public static void sendImage(File image,Socket socket) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream fileInputStream=new FileInputStream(image);
    int size=fileInputStream.available();

    byte[] imageByte=new byte[size];
    fileInputStream.read(imageByte);

    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    dataOutputStream.writeInt(imageByte.length);
    System.out.println(imageByte.length);
    dataOutputStream.write(imageByte);
    dataOutputStream.flush();

}
```

And fixed the receiver code:

```
private void show_imageFromService() throws IOException {

    DataInputStream dataInputStream=new DataInputStream(CreateActivity.client.socket.getInputStream());
    int size=dataInputStream.readInt();

    byte[] imageAr = new byte[size];
    int len = 0;
    while (len < size) {
        len += dataInputStream.read(imageAr, len, size - len);
    }

    Rect rect=new Rect();
    rect.set(imageView.getLeft(),imageView.getTop(),imageView.getRight(),imageView.getBottom());

    BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize=1;

    Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAr,0,imageAr.length,options);


    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

}
```

Now I success to show the image in Android.

Comment: You've ignored my comment about the return value of`read()`. Your use of `available()` here is a documented misuse: see the Javadoc. While you're there, have a look at the `readFully()` method,